# UIButton won't change picture when HighLighted, will only set picture to grey

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want the picture to turn yellow the second the user touches it. Right now on first tap the image turns a bit grey and on release turns yellow.
Second tap the picture would go back to red instantly. How can i fix this?

```
-(void)bMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 40, 40);
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: any special reason to use `UIControlEventTouchDown` instead of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`?

Comment: nop. Thought it would be more instant and won't wait for the user to release the finger.

Comment: have you tried setting `myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;`?

Comment: Yes, it will remove the grey coloring but still won't show me the yellow picture on highlight

Comment: yellow image was not displayed?

Comment: It was displayed only when I released my finger. Not when I'm on the button with the finger ( highlight)

Comment: i tested your code it's working fine.

Comment: @Sunny When you run my code and tap on the button and **keep** your finger on does the image change to yellow? I just started a new project just with the above and the image won't change to yellow when i tap and **keep** my finger on.

Comment: yes,yellow image came.

Comment: take another image and check it.

Comment: The image will turn yellow but only if you'll move your finger from the button or release your finger from the view. That's not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and it's working fine mate. Just double check the image names!

**EDIT 1:**

replace your code with the followings:

```
    -(void)bMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender.imageView.image != [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"]){
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 40, 40);
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
-(void)bMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    sender.highlighted = !sender.highlighted;  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{        
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    UIImage *buttonImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 40, 40);
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [myButton setImage:buttonImageSelected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}
```

Comment: When you run my code and tap on the button and **keep** your finger on does the image change to yellow? I just started a new project just with the above and the image won't change to yellow when i tap and **keep** my finger on.

Comment: No. I did take the finger off and it did turn yellow. Do u want it to be changed when the user keep the finger on the button?

Comment: Yes. I want the image to change to yellow instantly when the user touches the button and changes back instantly to red when the user touches it again.

Comment: change `(sender.imageView.image != [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"])` to `(sender.imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"])` to make it work. Why it's so complex to write a simple highlighted button (that works just fine if I set highlight image from the Interface Builder?

Comment: I did. I'm using the code and your answer solved my problem. I was just asking why I need to write so many lines of code to make a simple highlight work. Please fix the error from my last comment so I can accept.

Comment: Yes. The second solution is great. Thanks!